# Eclipse 2020-06 freezes constantly due to java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I have recently switched to eclipse 2020-06 for JEE development and it turned out to be a setback. It keeps freezing whenever an action is required: getting into a class definition, pulsing ctrl and selecting any item (classes, methods, ...). The eclipse log is full of these erros:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.LanguageServerWrapper.supportsWorkspaceFolderCapability(LanguageServerWrapper.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.LanguageServerWrapper.canOperate(LanguageServerWrapper.java:863)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.LanguageServiceAccessor.lambda$6(LanguageServiceAccessor.java:361)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.LanguageServiceAccessor.getLSWrappers(LanguageServiceAccessor.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.LanguageServiceAccessor.getLanguageServers(LanguageServiceAccessor.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.rename.LSPRenameHandler.isEnabled(LSPRenameHandler.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.isEnabled(HandlerProxy.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.canExecute(E4HandlerProxy.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.isEnabled(HandlerServiceHandler.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.isEnabled(Command.java:832)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.isEnabled(CommandContributionItem.java:917)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.updateMenuItem(CommandContributionItem.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.update(CommandContributionItem.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.update(CommandContributionItem.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.lambda$0(CommandContributionItem.java:935)
    at org.eclipse.jface.bindings.BindingManager.fireBindingManagerChanged(BindingManager.java:903)
    at org.eclipse.jface.bindings.BindingManager.setActiveBindings(BindingManager.java:2183)
    at org.eclipse.jface.bindings.BindingManager.recomputeBindings(BindingManager.java:1744)
    at org.eclipse.jface.bindings.BindingManager.contextManagerChanged(BindingManager.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.contexts.ContextManager.fireContextManagerChanged(ContextManager.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.contexts.ContextManager.setEventCaching(ContextManager.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.contexts.ContextManager.deferUpdates(ContextManager.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.AbstractPartRenderer.activate(AbstractPartRenderer.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.lambda$0(ContributedPartRenderer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4213)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setActiveControl(Shell.java:1469)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.WM_MOUSEACTIVATE(Shell.java:2315)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4784)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1480)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2142)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4931)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4841)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4931)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4841)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4931)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4841)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4931)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4841)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4931)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4841)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4931)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4841)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4931)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4841)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4931)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4841)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4931)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4841)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4931)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4841)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4931)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4841)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4931)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4841)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4931)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4841)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4931)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4841)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4931)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4841)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4931)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4841)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4931)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4841)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4931)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.callWindowProc(Label.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4841)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4931)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.PeekMessage(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3625)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1158)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1047)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)
```

The pluggins I'm currently using are JBoss Tools, Spring STS, Subeclipse and Dark Theme.
I've tried to download the whole IDE again and to uncheck most of the options regarding validations, to no avail. Any ideas?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Sounds like something to report via https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=LSP4E&component=General

Comment: I've tried to uninstall all the pluggins and install them back again. It seems that Jboss Tools pluggin is responsible for this erratic behaviour. I installed it again but only with the basic stuff and, apparently, the timeoutException seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 13):

Go to Windows -> Preferences -> Language servers. Disable all checkboxes, apply & close. Restart IDE. It solved problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was "Camel LSP server for java", in Language Servers. After disabling it, the GUI become responsive again

Answer (score -3):

In my case, Restarting IDE has resolved this issue.